# How to order association in descending order in Sequel

Tags: sequel

Given this class

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :rounds, order: :date
end
```

What I'm trying to do is sort by descending date.

I tried this like ActiveRecord supports, but that is not the way to go.

```
one_to_many :rounds, order: date: :desc
```

One solution is to create a dataset method but I feel there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use one of the many ["builders"](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/Builders.html) that come with Sequel.

This time namely the [`Sequel.desc`](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/Builders.html#method-i-desc) one.

```
one_to_many :rounds, order: Sequel.desc(:date)
```